# How to unlock horse masks in RDR2?

Tags: red-dead-online

Masks for your horse are probably one of the coolest things you can put on your horse in rdr2 online. I looked up on google, "How do you unlock horse masks?" and all that came up was:

1. Head to your nearest stable.
2. Go into “Tack and Services”
3. Go into “Saddles”
4. Select your current saddle.
5. Go down to the bottom of the list, where you'll see the “Masks” option.

But, it wont even let me click on the "Masks" option. Do I need to get one first? Or do I need to level up?
And if so, how do I even get one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horse masks are only available via [Outlaw Passes](https://www.rockstargames.com/reddeadonline/clubrewards).

The guide that you located was teaching you how to equip a horse mask earned by an Outlaw Pass.

Here are two quotes from the same [website](https://www.vg247.com/2019/09/11/red-dead-online-find-equip-horse-mask/) you went to:

> Most players’ first interaction with Horse Masks is via the Outlaw Club rewards.

> The Outlaw Club grants players 70 new tiers of items to unlock as they play the game, so there are plenty more cosmetics to enjoy.

This second [website](https://www.dailystar.co.uk/tech/gaming/red-dead-online-horse-masks-20048865) more specifically says you can get them as part of the Outlaw Pass only:

> You can get Horse Masks as rewards via the Outlaw Club, a new season-pass type item added to the game recently.